# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is truncating table if there is change in schema

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm creating a table in using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, But if there is change in table schema(structure) it is dropping the table and creating a new table.

I'm loosing my table data if it is dropping the table.

Is there any method to alter if there is change in schema ?

Comment: you can use migration script instead of dropping table every time.
Use  Flyway migration manager

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flyway to run DB migration script and you need not to drop table and create new one every time instead you can alter existing table. Then you can use  [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how.html) migration manager with your spring.